# How to rotate four sprites to the focus of these sprites

Tags: java, android, libgdx, rotation

I wrote the following code:

```
int a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0;
sprite[number[0]].setPosition(160, 600);
        sprite[number[1]].setPosition(560, 600);
        sprite[number[2]].setPosition(360, 400);
        sprite[number[3]].setPosition(360, 800);
        seiten[number[4]].setPosition(-35, 0);
        seiten1[number[4]].setPosition(825, 0);
        sprite[number[0]].setOrigin(200,0);
        sprite[number[1]].setOrigin(-200,0);
        sprite[number[2]].setOrigin(0,-200);
        sprite[number[3]].setOrigin(0,-200);
        sprite[number[0]].setRotation(a++);
        sprite[number[1]].setRotation(b++);
        sprite[number[2]].setRotation(c++);
        sprite[number[3]].setRotation(d++);
```

I want to rotate the sprites like:[image]
Unfortunately, this code doesn´t work for this purpose. How can I improve my code?

**EDIT:**

For better understanding:
I have ten sprites with different colors, four of them are shown on the game screen. The coincidence decides which sprite will be shown, but each sprite of them has a different color. Now I want to rotate the four sprites in the lane which is shown in the image. The four sprites should turn on the pink sprite which in fact doesn´t exist in my code. This pink sprite is just a symbol for the centre of the rotation (P(360|600)). The four sprites rotate all in the same lane.
With my code the four sprites rotate but not in the same lane as it is shown in the image. I hope my question is now more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use sprite.rotate() and set the sprite origin to the point you want to rotate about with sprite.setorigin().

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Sprite sprites[],centralSprite;
float centerX=200,centerY=200,radius=100;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

@Override
public void create() {

    spriteBatch=new SpriteBatch();

    Texture badlogic=new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
    centralSprite=new Sprite(badlogic);
    centralSprite.setSize(50,50);
    centralSprite.setPosition(centerX,centerY);
    centralSprite.setOriginCenter();

    sprites=new Sprite[4];

     for (int i=0;i<sprites.length;i++) {
        sprites[i] = new Sprite(badlogic);
        sprites[i].setSize(50,50);
        sprites[i].setRotation(90 * i);
        sprites[i].setPosition(centerX + radius * MathUtils.cosDeg(sprites[i].getRotation()),
                               centerY + radius * MathUtils.sinDeg(sprites[i].getRotation()));
        sprites[i].setOriginCenter();
    }

}

@Override
public void render() {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,0,1,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    spriteBatch.begin();

    for (int i=0;i<sprites.length;i++) {
        sprites[i].rotate(1);
        sprites[i].setPosition(centerX + radius * MathUtils.cosDeg(sprites[i].getRotation()),
                               centerY + radius * MathUtils.sinDeg(sprites[i].getRotation()));
        sprites[i].draw(spriteBatch);
    }

    centralSprite.draw(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.end();
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to just change the numbers in setOrigin to make the sprites rotate as I want? I tried many numbers, but nothing worked.

Comment: Is my solution not working according to your requirement  ?

Comment: No, unfortunately this solution doesn´t work, especially not for my purposes.

Comment: may be i don't understand your requirement, can you explain bit more what you want to achieve

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it is now more understandable.